# Simple PHP Dom Parser to find HTML ID with symbols

Tags: javascript, php, html, html-parsing

i have a problem with PHP simple HTML dom Parser.
I find a html ID with ® symbol but the API does not recognize (this class exists in the html file).

```
?>
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
require 'simple_html_dom.php';
$html = file_get_html('http://ark.intel.com/products/88194/Intel-Core-i7-6500U-Processor-4M-Cache-up-to-3_10-GHz');
//There is the problem on the ® symbol.
foreach($html->find('div#infosectionintel®platformprotectiontechnology-scrollpane') as $protection) {
$item8['osguardxx']     = $protection->find('tr#OSGuardTechVersion td.rc', 0)->plaintext;
$item8['txtxxxxxx']     = $protection->find('tr#TXT td.rc', 0)->plaintext;
$item8['exedisbit']     = $protection->find('tr#ExecuteDisable td.rc', 0)->plaintext;
$protections[] = $item8;
}
print_r($protections);
?>
```

I've test with other div# without symbols and works good!!
Thank's for help me!

Comment: Are you sure in the source there is ® symbol?  cause if you echoed it and got the id from there, browser can make `&reg` to that symbol!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either use [`chr($ascii)`](http://no.php.net/chr) (Replace ascii with ascii code for ®) or you can use wildcards like this:

```
foreach($html->find('div[id*=infosectionintel]', 0) as $protection) {
```

And it will look for any div id which has **`infosectionintel`** in it's name.

Comment: Glad I could help Tarik :)